# Equivalent of Python's 'if ..... in ......' in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, if-statement, python-3.x

Python has an 'if... in...' statement which allows a person to create a list, and using the 'if... in...' statement the person can check if a specified something is present in the list. For example, to check if a particular letter is present in a list of vowels. So basically:

```
vowels = [list-of-vowels]
if 'e' in vowels:
    (do something)
```

So is there any ***simple*** equivalent of the 'if in' statement of Python in Java?

Comment: what about "contains"? perhaps take a look at the class api you are trying to use..

Comment: nit: There's no `if ... in ...` statement. There's the `if` statement, and the `in` operator.

Comment: +1, because what's obvious to us Java folks may not be obvious to Python folks. When I first started using Python (from a Java background), I sometimes got confused as to why there's no `contains` method on py collections; I forgot that python uses a language construct for that. So I'm sympathetic to someone who goes the other way around and can't find the language construct, forgetting that in Java it's done via a plain ol' method.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `contains` method in containers:

```
if ( container.contains( element ) ){
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for lists you can use the .contains() method

for numbers, you need to establish a range manually( i.e. `if(i>0 && i <10)`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't am sure if is that you pretend...

```
        char vowels[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
            if (vowels[i] == 'e') {
                System.out.println("We find the e!!!!!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the more close to the "in" of python, it does exactly what you want, you can change for everyone type of data, that you want...

```
        char vowels[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

        for (char Value : vowels) {
            if (Value == 'e') {
                System.out.println("We find the e!!!!!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f.f.g code.

```
String v = "aeiou";
if(v.containsIgnoreCase("e"){
System.out.println("e located sir/mam");
}
```